# ECG Circuit Simulation problems

Tags: operational-amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier, biopotential

I'm working on a [TINA-TI circuit](http://prntscr.com/2tf33d). I'm no expert in the electronics field or the medical engineering so I am having a hard time figuring out how to construct my ECG circuit. This signal will be connected to an Arduino, so I want the Vout to lie between 0V and 5V, to use the whole workspace of the A2D in the Arduino.
[image]
A couple of things I wonder about:

When I run a Transient-analysis, the graph tells me that my Vout is between 2.50V and 2.50V and I cant seem to figure it out. I want the signal's virtual ground to be 2,5V (or maybe less) and the signal to swing from 0V to 5V.

I'm also unsure about the supply minus voltage on the INA333 and the OPA333. Which should be me virtual ground, which should be ground or if some should be negative Vcc. As I've already mentioned my electronics skills are not good, so excuse me for any obvious mistakes.

Comment: Agreed.  A link to a schematic image file will do, and someone with enough rep will edit to embed in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at your circuit (unless you post a schematic), at least your parts seem right.  Personally, I'd recommend the AD623 over the INA333 (of course, I don't actually know your specs, so take w/ grain of salt) simply because the inputs on the 623 can actually go a tad BELOW the low rail, which is a huge benefit.

The way to achieve what you're trying to do is an instrum. amp. stage with V+ as 5V, V- as ground, and Vref as 2.5V.  You'll need to buffer the 2.5V before putting it in to Vref.  A voltage follower there is pretty standard.  The Instr. amp.  should have a modest gain of about 10, to avoid saturating on differences in electrode skin potentials.  The inputs of the amp will go to the two ECG leads, and the ground can go to the leg lead.

After the input stage, you want to filter with a low-freq cutoff of about 0.1Hz and a high-freq cutoff of about 110Hz,  and then an amplifier stage w/ a gain of about 150.  You can build your low-pass into your amp stage, but you should hig-pass before you amplify.

Comment: If you want you can add a notch filter @ 50/60Hz for further improvement. Also there is a few analog front end chips designed for ECG specifically over at TI.com.